# Append dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, append

I am trying to get stock price from Tiingo and append dataframes

```
    data = pd.DataFrame()   

    lis=[ 
"AAPL",
"MSFT",
"AMZN",
"GOOGL",
"TSLA",
"GOOG",
"NVDA",
"FB",
"JPM",
"BAC",
"ADBE",
"MA",
"PFE",
"DIS",
"NFLX",
"INTC",
"VZ",
"MO"
]

for i in lis:
      data =data.append(client.get_dataframe([i],
                                      frequency='weekly',
                                      metric_name='close',
                                      startDate='2020-03-01',
                                      endDate='2021-12-10'))
```

however, the result shows a bit different:

```
             AAPL  MFST
2020-03-01   100   NAN
2020-03-02   101   NAN
2020-03-03   103   NAN
...                NAN
2021-12-10   120   NAN

2020-03-01   NAN   600
2020-03-02   NAN   400
2020-03-03   NAN   300
...          NAN   
2021-12-10   NAN   1100
```

how can I make it look like this:

```
             AAPL  MFST
2020-03-01   100   600
2020-03-02   101   400
2020-03-03   103   300
...                
2021-12-10   120   1100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can't change the method to produce the initial input, you can fix it using `groupby`:

```
data = data.groupby(level=0).max()
```

Answer (score 0):

append method appends new rows. And that is exactly what you see as a result. You need to make join but not append.

try this:

```
new_data = client.get_dataframe([i],
                                      frequency='weekly',
                                      metric_name='close',
                                      startDate='2020-03-01',
                                      endDate='2021-12-10')
data.join(new_data)
```

docs for df.join() method are availuable here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using pandas `DataFrame.append` method you could try pandas concatenate method.

```
import pandas as pd
dfs = []
for i in lis:
      dfs.append(client.get_dataframe([i],
                                      frequency='weekly',
                                      metric_name='close',
                                      startDate='2020-03-01',
                                      endDate='2021-12-10'))
data = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1) # set axis = 1 to concate by columns, not rows!
```

Note, that this assumes your list of dfs has a) a common index and b) no extra columns besides say `AAPL` and `MSFT`.

If needed, you could also try merging:

```
from functools import reduce
data = reduce(lambda df1,df2: pd.merge(df1,df2,on='id'), dfs)
```

where `id` would be the column you that all dfs you pulled from client have in common. You may not need this since you have matching indexes and want to concatenate columns.